# What does ::: mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm reading a js file for transforming of one spatial model(.gml). from a specific projection to another. What does ":::" mean in the code as follows?

```
_getTransformation(projectionFrom, projectionTo) {
    let cacheKey = `${projectionFrom}:::${projectionTo}`;
    if (!this.transformations[cacheKey]) {
      let from = this._getProjection(projectionFrom);
      let to = this._getProjection(projectionTo);
      this.transformations[cacheKey] = proj4(from, to);
    }
    return this.transformations[cacheKey];
}
```

Comment: That is just a string. Pretty much like - `projectionFrom + ":::" + projectionTo`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thank you for answering my first question in stack overflow~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string with ` is called a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), it's an ES6 string making multiple lines and interpolation easier. The `:::` is just a collection of three characters in the string. It's equivalent to:

```
let cacheKey = projectionFrom + ":::" + projectionTo;
```

No special characters involved bar the `${}` - that signifies that the contents should be treated like an expression, the result of which is inserted into the string.

Comment: No worries @Bayernzc, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.